E: Работа dpkg была прервана, вы должны вручную запустить «sudo dpkg --configure -a» для устранения проблемы крутится бесконечно
Устанавливал приложение, во время установки ноут выключился. При повторной попытке установки пишет :
E: Работа dpkg была прервана, вы должны вручную запустить «sudo dpkg --configure -a» для устранения проблемы. 


При попытке установить любое другое приложение или модуль возникает та же ошибка, при использовании рекомендованной команды sudo dpkg --configure -a уходит в бесконечное ожидание:
Laptop-QN190HKL ~ > sudo dpkg --configure -a
Настраивается пакет context (2021.03.05.20220211-1) …
Running mtxrun --generate. This may take some time... done.
Pregenerating ConTeXt MarkIV format. This may take some time... 



Отмените выполнение ctrl+c
Запустите sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-overwrite

потом выполните sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get autoremove

затем попробуйте установить необходимый Вам пакет, если не поможет воспользуйтесь apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean

так-же возможно поможет в восстановлении зависимостей sudo apt-get install -f

sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-overwrite тоже висит бесконечно

Посмотрите вывод с разными вариантами отладки (dpkg --debug=help). Если ситуация не прояснится, попробуйте запустить процесс под strace. Может, станет понятнее на ожидании какого ресурса висит.

Комп слабый
врятли висит - просто долго делает... попробуйте дождаться.

Настраивается пакет context

и не может настроиться... это "мощная надстройка над TeX" - если не пользуетесь TeX, то удалите этот пакет.
dpkg -r context

потом
dpkg --configure -a
apt -f install

Если зависимости его тянут, то удалите ещё и зависимости.
Второй вариант
Можно рискнуть и пропустить настройку пакета. Для этого удалите файлы
/var/lib/dpkg/info/context.config 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/context.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/context.postinst

и повторите dpkg --configure -a

компик нормальный, новый ,рязань 7 5600 16 ядер, 32 оперы, как раз когда устанавливал латех, комп разрядился и выключился, попробую дождаться, спасибо, утром отпишу

Всю ночь работал, нет результата,  висит в том же месте

если разрядился - значит что-то зависимое криво поставилось. удаляй всё что успело поставиться из латеха.

Спасибо, всё-таки удалил преинст и постинст помогло действительно
